# Loading Masonry before RequireJS (remove initialize delay)

Tags: requirejs, masonry

I am trying to load Masonry with RequireJS and everything works fine, but there is visible delay right after page load (grid elements "jumps" after Masonry is loaded). Without RequireJS it works fine, so is it possible to load Masonry script before RequireJS?

Here is an example with RequireJS - jsfiddle.net/Desvelo1/c9va07vc/3 - and here without it - jsfiddle.net/Desvelo1/26mudgsv/2 As you can see in version with RequireJS there is visible "jump" when masonry is loaded. Is it possible to remove such delay?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Why do you want to use RequireJS for such a small application? or is it large?

Comment: This is only small part of application I am working on - RequireJS is required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that design of your script is optimal - I'm a bit confused by nested `requirejs` calls. Are they necessary?

Anyway, regarding your question. Try to use such config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.11.1.min',
        masonry: 'masonry.pkgd.min',
        lazyload: 'jquery.lazyload.min'
    },
    deps: ['masonry'] // <- this is the changes
});
```

Reference to the docs: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps

Comment: Thanks. Nesting `requirejs` calls wasn't necessary so I have removed it. About your suggestion unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm not sure is it possible to make it with RequireJS, couse `data-main="js/main"` is always loaded after RequireJS and maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Could you please show some example in `jsfiddle` (or similar) service?

Comment: Hi, Here is an example with RequireJS - http://jsfiddle.net/Desvelo1/c9va07vc/3/ - and here without it - http://jsfiddle.net/Desvelo1/26mudgsv/2/  As you can see in version with RequireJS there is visible "jump" when masonry is loaded. Is it possible to remove such delay?